# How to show Multiple Notifications on a particular day in different times

Tags: android, notifications

In my android app I need to show 8 notifications on a particular day for example (21-11-2015) at different times,I'm able to how only 1 notification using alarm manager class but I should also show remaining 7 notifications with different content.

Here is MyActivity

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    cal.clear();
    cal.set(2015, 10, 20, 14, 18);
    cal.set(2015, 10, 20, 14, 20);

    Intent myIntent1 = new Intent(this, AlarmBroadCustReciver.class);

    Intent myIntent2 = new Intent(this, AlarmBroadCustReciver.class);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent1 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 1253, myIntent1,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent2 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 1263, myIntent2,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);


    AlarmManager alarmManager1 = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

    alarmManager1.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent1);
    alarmManager1.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent2);
```

Here is AlarmReceiver

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class AlarmBroadCustReciver extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Toast.makeText(context, "Alarm worked.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set different times in the calendar object and then use the object to set an alarm using the AlarmManager.

You can set all the alarms at the same time, they will be executed at the time for which they are set.

**Your code (modified by me) :-**

```
    AlarmManager alarmManager1 = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    Intent myIntent1 = new Intent(this, AlarmBroadCustReciver.class);
    myIntent1.setAction(ACTION_ONE);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent1 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 1253, myIntent1,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    // Set the time for first alarm here
    cal.set(2015, 10, 20, 14, 18);
    alarmManager1.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent1);
    Intent myIntent2 = new Intent(this, AlarmBroadCustReciver.class);
    myIntent2.setAction(ACTION_TWO);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent2 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 1263, myIntent2,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    // Set the time for second alarm here
    cal.set(2015, 10, 20, 14, 20);
    alarmManager1.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent2);
    // In this way set time for all the rest of the alarms
```

**Your BroadcastReceiver class will look like this :-**

```
    public class AlarmBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);
        builder.setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.mipmap.ic_launcher));
        builder.setContentTitle(context.getString(R.string.app_name));
        if (intent.getAction().equalsIgnoreCase(ACTION_ONE)) {
            builder.setContentText("Alarm one");
        } else {
            builder.setContentText("Alarm two");
        }
        Notification notification = builder.build();
        int notificationID = 0;
        notificationManager.notify(notificationID, notification);
        // If you want two notifications simultaneously, change the notificationID (written in above line of code) for every notification.
    }
}
```

**Please note, ACTION_ONE and ACTION_TWO are two string constants**

Comment: I have done same thing but it only works for the latest time.

Comment: no I need to show the notifications only for one day

Comment: Ok, I got what you were trying to ask. In a calendar object we can add any date and time by the following method :-  calendar.set(year, month, day, hour, minute, seconds);

Comment: No, I had to set the notifications for different times,I have edited the question please have a look

Comment: I've modified your code and added in my answer above. Please do have a look.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95662/discussion-between-sunil-and-varun-kumar).

Comment: tq varun its working well,but how to change the content in the notifications?

Comment: Ur welcome Sunil, check out the discussion in the chat from the link you posted above. I've explained the complete process there. If you have any further questions, feel free to ask them.

Comment: Example has been posted. Check my answer, it has been updated with your final code.

Comment: tried with your updated code but still I'm unable to receive notification.

Comment: Oh sorry, I forgot to tell you to register your broadcast receiver in the manifest file. Do this inside your Android Manifest file in the <application> tag :- <receiver android:name="<enter name of your broadcast receiver along with package"/>

Comment: I've answered your queries in the discussion session as well. Please do have a look.